# How to show the operation_id in drf_spectacular?

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

Is there a way to show the `operation_id` in `drf_spectacular` like it is shown in `drf_yasg`? The docs don't show anything regarding this setting. The `operation_id` is used in our code generators, so it is very practical to view it in the overview.

[image: Swagger UI without the operation_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, just not very findable. It is a setting in the Swagger UI, which is listed [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/).

```
'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
    'displayOperationId': True,
}
```

With this added to the `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS`, the operation_id shows up in the Swagger UI.

[image: Swagger UI with the operation_id]